# Volume of the region bounded by curves

Tags: calculus

> Find the volume $V$ of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line:  $y = x$, $y = 0$, $x = 4$, $x = 8$;  about $x = 1$.

I have drawn the figure and found out how it would look like
so far I have written this formula
$$V=2\pi\int_{4}^{8} (x-1)(x-0) dx.$$

Am I doing it right? Also I don't understand the significance of this formula. Where does this formula come from? Thanks.

Comment: looks like you got it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula represents cylindrical shells.

We know that the surface area of a cylinder is $2πrh$.

We know that $r$ is the distance between the point on the curve and the line of rotation.

IN this case, $r=(x-1)$, because your line is $x=1$.

$H$ is your function, which in this case, $h=x$.

We also have that $dx$ is the thickness of the "shell."

Answer (score 1):

Your evaluation is correct. You are integrating cylindrical cells with base area $2\pi(x-1)dx$ and the height of $x$ for $x\in [4,8]$.

This is an alternative way. By translation, the volume can be obtained by rotating the region bounded by $y = x+1$, $y = 0$, $x = 3$, $x = 7$;  about $x =0$. After taking a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution), you should obtain that 
$$V=\pi\int_{y=0}^4(7^2-3^2)dy+\pi\int_{y=4}^8(7^2-(y-1)^2) dy=\frac{752\pi}{3}.$$